# htaccess domain and subdomain redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have this configuration which is direct any URL to the  "public_html" directory and hide the "public_html".

```
# Add trailing slash if path does not contain a period or end with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.kent.gd/$1/ [R=301,L]

#Rewrites http://www.yoursite.com/subdir to http://www.yoursite.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/$1 [L]
```

Now I have added some subdomain , which I don’t want my subdomain to redirect like main domain.

I have tried this but not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.kent\.gd$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.kent.gd /$1 [L]
```

Comment: ¿How is the URL for the sub-domain you added? Give an example, please. ¿Do the top rule sets work?

Comment: u.kent.gd and d.kent.gd , but i want to make it as wildcard